# Datagrid text alignment

Tags: wpf, datagrid, c#-4.0, wpftoolkit

I was wondering if anyone had an easy way to get the text in a WPF data grid to be center aligned. I got the data grid to work just fine, but the right text alignment bothered me. I goggled some, and downloaded the wpftoolkit, but the examples either do not work, or give me a compile error. I did add the reference to the wpftoolkit to my project. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

the xaml for the data grid is as follows

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="15,15,10,65" Name="DG1" CanUserReorderColumns="False" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you set the [Block.TextAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.textalignment.aspx) property to Center on the DataGrid, it will be inherited by the TextBlocks and TextBoxes used in DataGridTextColumns and will center the text:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid
    Block.TextAlignment="Center"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    Margin="15,15,10,65"
    Name="DG1"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" />
```

If you want to align text in the cells but not in the headers or elsewhere in the Grid, you can set the property on the DataGridCell using CellStyle:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    Margin="15,15,10,65"
    Name="DG1"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False">
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="WpfToolkit:DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: this helped me thanks! I was using Control.HorizontalAlignment x_x

Comment: If you want to get more fine grained, you can also set the ElementStyle property on individual columns.  You probably want to use BasedOn="{x:Static DataGridTextColumn.DefaultElementStyle}" in that case.