# Center datagrid combobox text

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I center the text of ComboBox columns in a DataGridView?

The DataGrid is dynamically updated with columns of different types:

```
foreach (Fields field in fields)
                {
                    if (field.group.Count > 1)
                    {
                        DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                        column.Header = field.name;
                        column.ItemsSource = field.group;
                        column.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(field.name)
                        {

                        };
                        dgwDataMain.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        column.Header = field.name;
                        column.Binding = new Binding(field.name)
                        {
                            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                            NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true,
                            NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true
                        };
                        dgwDataMain.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for WinForm `DataGridView`:

In your code where you creating a ComboBox columns add next row:

```
column.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

Comment: DataGridTextColumn has no definition for DefaultCellStyle.

Comment: @Ice 13 I was wonder too, when seen a "WPF" tag. On my information WPF doesn't have a DataGridView.

Comment: it has System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid

Comment: I am not familiar with WPF, but only I know you need workaround with <Style>. @Ice 13 and remove `datagridview`, and `datagridviewcombobox` tags from your question, please...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @Ice 13, if you will get a working solution for this question, please add own answer here, just for next users...

Comment: @Ice 13, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652318/datagrid-text-alignment. There some example of creating own style for DataGridCell, if it can be used in your DataGridComboBox...

Comment: I have to disable AutoGenerateColumns and it only works for TextBoxColumns (not for ComboBoxColumns).